# CKEditor 4.3.4 - Response script is not evaluated

Tags: file-upload, coldfusion, ckeditor

I am trying to make uploading possible for CKEditor. I added the uploadUrl in my config:

```
config.filebrowserUploadUrl = cfData.jsService+'?method=uploadImage';
```

In my backend I use Coldfusion to upload the image, and create the the return script:

```
<cffunction name="uploadImage" access="remote" output="false" returntype="string" returnformat="plain">
    <cfargument name="upload" required="true">
    <cfargument name="CKEditorFuncNum" type="numeric" requited="false">

    ... // image upload logic

    <cfreturn "<script type=""text/javascript"">window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction("& arguments.CKEditorFuncNum &", '[dynamic-image-url]', '');</script>">
</cffunction>
```

The response tab in Chrome shows the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(1, '[dynamic-image-url]', '');</script>
```

Everything seems to go well, but then the code is printed as string in the DOM, instead as HTML:
[image]

Is there something I am doing wrong? I know it's not the version, as CKFinder also uses 4.3.4 and it works for them (http://cksource.com/ckfinder/demo#ckeditor).

N.B. When I evaluate the callFunction by running it in the console, the image is shown in the image-popup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it just after typing this question, small mistake... I gave the wrong `content-type` header (`text/plain`).

Fixing that in CF is quite easy:

```
cfcontent type="text/html">
```